# Intellij IDEA - Event logs printing multiple times

Tags: intellij-idea, event-log

In the latest version of `Intellij IDEA (Community 2020.1)`, logs in the **Event Log** section are printing four times. Image below.

[image]

Anyone can share steps to fix this?

**Update**

List of all plugins installed in Intellij

Smali Support (201.7223.91)
Ant (201.7223.91)
Gradle (201.7223.91)
Maven (201.7223.91)
Code Coverage for Java (201.7223.91)
XPathView + XSLT (201.7223.91)
XSLT Debugger (201.7223.91)
Settings Repository (201.7223.91)
JavaFX (201.7223.91)
Groovy (201.7223.91)
Markdown (201.7223.91)
Properties (201.7223.91)
Resource Bundle Editor (201.7223.91)
Shell Script (201.7223.91)
YAML (201.7223.91)
Plugin DevKit (201.7223.91)
UI Designer (201.7223.91)
JUnit (201.7223.91)
TestNG (201.7223.91)
ChangeReminder (201.7223.91)
Git (201.7223.91)
GitHub (201.7223.91)
Mercurial (201.7223.91)
Subversion (201.7223.91)
Bytecode Viewer (201.7223.91)
Copyright (201.7223.91)
Eclipse Interoperability (201.7223.91)
EditorConfig (201.7223.91)
Grazie (201.7223.91)
IntelliLang (201.7223.91)
Java Bytecode Decompiler (201.7223.91)
Java Internationalization (201.7223.91)
Java Stream Debugger (201.7223.91)
Kotlin (1.3.72-release-IJ2020.1-1)
Machine Learning Code Completion (201.7223.91)
Next File Prediction (201.7223.91)
Task Management (201.7223.91)
Terminal (201.7223.91)
TextMate bundles (201.7223.91)

Comment: Is it reproducible with new sample project?

Comment: I am not sure. I am getting this since I am using new Intellij for my organization's project. With 2018 version of Intellij with same project I didn't faced this.

Comment: Are there any custom plugins installed?

Comment: @y.bedrov I have udpated the question with list of plugins installed.

Comment: Please try to check the issue with new sample project as I couldn't reproduce the issue on my side.